# What is the best way to transfer 'develop' branch from repository B to repository A's subdirectory with commit history using Bitbucket UI or terminal?

Tags: github, bitbucket, git-commit

I want to transfer "develop" branch of repository B to repository A's subdirectory named "xyz" under branch "main/develop" of repository A by preserving all commit history of repository B for branch "develop".

Can someone please suggest solution from mac terminal or UI of bitbucket.

I have tried bundle, subtree, submodule, mirror, bare, but some transfers the data with no commit history and git filter-repo doesn't help me transfer the files itself.